# What element is the default scrollbar handler?

Tags: html, dom, cross-browser, scrollbar, overflow

Does every browser out there share any standard about what element is the default handler for displaying scrollbars? I'm really wondering how do they treat the rendering of `<html>` and `<body>` elements

**Update:**

For instance, if you have to reconstruct the DOM architecture where would you put the `overflow: auto/scroll` in the `<html>` or `<body>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

> For instance, if you have to reconstruct the DOM architecture where
>   would you put the overflow: auto/scroll in the  or ?

As far as this is concerned, the [HTML element is the one you're after](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html).

---

**Original Answer:**

Scrollbar styling is browser dependant to some degree, and can only be controlled via CSS for Webkit browsers and IE, the alternative would be to utilise javascript plugins.

The one consistent control CSS has is whether to display scrollbars or not for a given element, using [the `overflow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

> The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element.

Regarding your styling options, [example implementations in CSS may be](http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/):

Internet Explorer

```
body{
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Webkit

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 3px; height: 3px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #666; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #999;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 50px; background-color: #666; border-radius: 3px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #999;}}
::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;}
```

As far as the default 'handler' is concerned, CSS is **cascading** so apply any rules to the top level for which you want all children to inherit those properties.

As far as the window scrollbars are concerned, you want to control these using the `html` element, as this is the element that always fills the viewport/content space.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not asking only about styling. When I talk about a "default handler" is because when animating the window scrollbar in JavaScript, you need to specify an element as `window`, `code`, `html` or `body`

Maybe I should update the tags of my post

Comment: The `html` element is what you're after, see http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html

Comment: This is whats confusing me while inspecting the Google Results page @ Chrome/Webkit34.0.1847.116 `$('body').scrollTop --> 522`  `$('html').scrollTop --> 0` You know what I mean?